# mutate_each for selected columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have question about applying `function` to my data.frame with `mutate_each`

I have a function which calculates phase shift in between two waves `y1` and `y2`. I want to apply this function to my data and create new column with named `phase` but I'm getting an error which says one of the argument is missing `y2` even though I put them in my `function`.

maybe I'm not good at writing function:)

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(psd) # Loaded psd (1.0.1) -- Adaptive multitaper spectrum estimation

time <- seq(1,30)
y1 <- sort(runif(30,-0.014,0.014),decreasing=TRUE)
y2 <- sort(runif(30,-0.012,0.012),decreasing=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(y1,y2,time)
#calculation phase difference between two waves y1 and y2  

phase_diff <- function(y1,y2,time){
  out1=pspectrum(y1*(-1),x.frqsamp = 0.1);
  out2=pspectrum(y2*(-1),x.frqsamp = 0.1);
  f1 = out1$freq[which.min(out1$spec)];
  f2 <- out2$freq[which.min(out2$spec)];
  fit1 <- lm(y1 ~ sin(2*pi*f1*time)+cos(2*pi*f1*time));
  fit2 <- lm(y2 ~ sin(2*pi*f2*time)+cos(2*pi*f2*time));
  a1 <- fit1$coefficients[2];
  b1 <- fit1$coefficients[3];
  ph1 <- atan(b1/a1);
  a2 <- fit2$coefficients[2];
  b2 <- fit2$coefficients[3];
  ph2 <- atan(b2/a2);
  phase_difference <- as.numeric((ph2-ph1)/pi);
  return(phase_difference)
}

dff <- df%>%
mutate_each(funs(phase_diff),phase=c(y1,y2,time))

Stage  0 est. (pilot) 
    environment  ** .psdEnv **  refreshed
    detrending (and demeaning)
Stage  1 est. (Ave. S.V.R. -10.9 dB) 
Stage  2 est. (Ave. S.V.R. -8.3 dB) 
Stage  3 est. (Ave. S.V.R. -8.3 dB) 
Stage  4 est. (Ave. S.V.R. -8.3 dB) 
Stage  5 est. (Ave. S.V.R. -8.3 dB) 
Normalized  single-sided  psd estimates ( psd ) for sampling-freq.  0.1
Error: argument "y2" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: Your initial dataset hava only three columns 'y1', 'y2', 'time', and these are arguments for the 'phase_diff` function.  I don't understand why you are using `mutate_each`.  Simply `phase_diff(df$y1, df$y2, df$time)` should return an output.  The `mutate_each is for applying to each column, and I don't see it useful here (unless I am mistaken)

Comment: @akrun thanks for inquiry. I have other things to do in my `dplyr` chain of my real data. So I would like to stick with `mutate_each`:)

Comment: Please check the solution I posted.  You can use `mutate` if you want to do other things in the `dplyr` chain (based on the example showed).

Comment: @akrun ok I just saw it. Thanks man. but why `mutate_each` doesnt work?

Comment: It is applying the `phase_diff` to the first column 'y1', then to 'y2' and to 'time'.  But, for each of the columns, there are no corresponding input variables (as the function requires 3 variables)

Comment: @akrun ow Ok I see. Salute man. always;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we need to create a new column, and the function `phase_diff` utilizes all the columns in the input dataset as argument, the OP may need `mutate` instead of `mutate_each.  The`mutate_each` is for applying to each column in the dataset.

```
res <- df %>%
          mutate(phase = phase_diff(y1, y2, time))
head(res,2)
#         y1          y2 time      phase
# 1 0.01398857 0.010296090    1 -0.1349023
# 2 0.01334217 0.009990988    2 -0.1349023
```

The above operation can be done using `base R`

```
phase_diff(df$y1, df$y2, df$time)
```